# Django ListView pages and links

Tags: django, url, django-urls

I am using a Django `ListView` with `pagination` to organize my blog posts. I also set up a slug for each post, but once the post gets onto page 2+, clicking on the post link on the page adds the page number to the url. For example:

Clicking on a link on page 1: `www.foo.com/myslug`

Clicking on a link on page x (not 1): `www.foo.com/x/myslug`

How can I make sure clicking the link goes to the url of the post? This is how I have it set up:

**HTML Extension**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
    ...
    <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
    ...
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a id='newer' href="/{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}/">← Newer &nbsp;</a>
    {% endif %}
    <span id='pages' class="text-muted">Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a id='older' href="/{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}/">&nbsp; Older →</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**URLS**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# index
url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)?/?$', ListView.as_view(
    model=Post,
    paginate_by=5,
    )),
# individual posts
url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', DetailView.as_view(model=Post,
    )),
)
```

Comment: Why not use querystring variables for the page numbers and leave it out of the URL routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because get_absolute_url is not defined properly. You should override that method to return that post url. Based on your code:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/%s/" % self.slug
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about the forward slash